# Excel: Make a dynamic sum formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to make a dynamic sum formula in excel, which I've indicated in the screenshot. As you can see, the rows are the same except for H2, H3, H4, and H5. Instead of repeatedly adding more and more rows, I would like to have a cell that references how many of them should be there.

I understand that this is essentially a sum with i-->n, and a for loop would be fitting here, but I'm curious if this could be achieved without VBA. Any ideas?

Formula example:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(INDEX(
INDEX(INDIRECT('Process Hotels'!H2&MATCH('Process Hotels'!E2,'Input Hotels'!D:D)):INDIRECT("AI"&MATCH('Process Hotels'!E2,'Input Hotels'!D:D)),0)+
INDEX(INDIRECT('Process Hotels'!H3&MATCH('Process Hotels'!E2,'Input Hotels'!D:D)):INDIRECT("AI"&MATCH('Process Hotels'!E2,'Input Hotels'!D:D)),0)+
INDEX(INDIRECT('Process Hotels'!H4&MATCH('Process Hotels'!E2,'Input Hotels'!D:D)):INDIRECT("AI"&MATCH('Process Hotels'!E2,'Input Hotels'!D:D)),0)+
INDEX(INDIRECT('Process Hotels'!H5&MATCH('Process Hotels'!E2,'Input Hotels'!D:D)):INDIRECT("AI"&MATCH('Process Hotels'!E2,'Input Hotels'!D:D)),0),
0),""))
```

[Formula example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI0Ri.png)

Comment: @P.b Added the formula to the post

Comment: Maybe something like this: `=BYROW('Process Hotels'!H2:H5,LAMBDA(x,MIN(IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(INDIRECT(x&MATCH('Process Hotels'!E2,'Input Hotels'!D:D)):INDIRECT("AI"&MATCH('Process Hotels'!E2,'Input Hotels'!D:D)),0),0),""))))` (unable to test)

Comment: Hey @p.b., I've made another question here since the formula in this one is not really clear. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73427589/19808006. I'd appreciate if you could take a look!